# regular expression to detect numbers written as words

Tags: php, regex

I need PHP code to detect whether a string contains 4 or more consecutive written numbers (0 to 9), like :

```
"one four six nine five"
```

or

```
"zero eight nine nine seven three six six"
```

Comment: Can the numbers be arbitrarily large?

Comment: Is "one hundred forty six" one number? Two numbers? Three? Four?

Comment: only single numbers zero till nine

Comment: So is the twelve in your example irrelevant? Would "one four six twelve" match or not?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
\b(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)(?: +|$)){4}
```

[(Rubular)](http://rubular.com/r/DSjpVA6OVK)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is:

```
\b(?:(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero)\b\s*?){4}
```

That's pretty much the same as the rest. The only interesting bit is the `\s*?` part - that will lazily match the spaces between the words, so you don't end up with extra spaces *after* the sequence of 4 words. The `\b` before it assures there's at least a single space (or other separator after the last word, so `!a b c d!` will match)

Comment: +1 I quite like this approach. Here's a Rubular link for it: http://rubular.com/r/Fm4dGwkNGg ... You forgot zero though.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks. I tested it there too, just forgot the link. I have zero, but it isn't sorted `:)`

Comment: Oh yeah, it's sorted in keyboard order. I should have noticed that zero is one of the examples in the rubular link. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?:(?:^|\s)(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)(?=\s|$)){4,}/
```

PHP code:

```
if (preg_match(...put regex here..., $stringToTestAgainst)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note: More words (e.g. 'twelve') can easily be added to the regex.

Comment: @Sherif, yes. Note that you'll need to put the regex in a string (`"/.../"`), and you'll probably need to escape the `\s` (=>`\\s`).

Comment: Allowed numbers are from zero to nine but not ten

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/(?:\b(?:(one)|(two)|(three)|(four)|(five)|(six)|(seven)|(eight)|(nine))\b\s*?){4,}/", $variable_to_test_against, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added space(s) in the regular expression - thanks to Kobi.

Comment: Aren't you missing spaces between the words?