# regular expression to detect numbers written as words - UTF-8 input

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match, arabic

thanks for the answers to :

"regular expression to detect numbers written as words" :

[regular expression to detect numbers written as words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608159/regular-expression-to-detect-numbers-written-as-words)

I now have this working, however I have the same requirement but the numbers as words are in Arabic (or any other UTF-8) and not English, so :

```
if (preg_match("/\p{L}\b(?:(?:واحد|اثنان|ثلاثة|أربعة|خمسة|ستة|سبعة|ثمانية|تسعة|صفر|عشرة)\b\s*?){4}/", $str, $matches) > 0) 
   return true;
```

Does not work - I've googled and there seems to be quite a few issues with preg_match and UTF-8 string but I couldn't get any of the suggestions found to work. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that - aside from the character encoding - there will also be "Arabic as a right-to-left language" problem which I've no idea how to deal with.

Comment: @msw, right to left has to do with displaying data, but the data are still stored in bytes sequenced in the string. doesn't matter whether RTL or LTR.

Comment: Is this PHP?  Have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\b` may not be working as you expect. `\b` specifies a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), but what is considered a word character by PCRE depends on what locale the script is running in (take a look towards the bottom of the [PCRE escape sequences](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) manual page):

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

You might also want to read [Handling UTF-8 with PHP](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) (the section on PCRE in particular).

Instead, you could use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in conjunction with a Unicode character property to emulate a word boundary: `(?<=\P{L})`. This asserts that the previous character is **not** a unicode "letter".

So all together it would look like:

```
/(?<=\P{L})(?:(?:واحد|اثنان|ثلاثة|أربعة|خمسة|ستة|سبعة|ثمانية|تسعة|صفر|عشرة)\s*?){4}/
```

Answer (score 0):

convert both pattern and `$str` to `windows-1256`, do the matching, then convert `$matches` items back (if needed), this is the solution I came to after suffering for some time.

```
$pattern="/\p{L}\b(?:(?:واحد|اثنان|ثلاثة|أربعة|خمسة|ستة|سبعة|ثمانية|تسعة|صفر|عشرة)\b\s*?){4}/";
$pattern_windows1265 = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $pattern);
$str_windows1265 = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $str);
if (preg_match($pattern_windows1265, $str_windows1265, $matches) > 0) 
   return true;
```

Here's a test example to check if unicode conversion is allowing Arabic letters match in preg_match:

```
<?php
$pattern="/(واحد|اثنان|ثلاثة|أربعة|خمسة|ستة|سبعة|ثمانية|تسعة|صفر|عشرة)/";
$pattern_windows1265 = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $pattern);


$test_cases=array(
    'لدي أربعة أولاد',
    'قفز الثعلب فوق الشجرة',
    'عندي خمسة أرانب',
);
foreach ($test_cases as $str) {
    $str_windows1265 = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $str);

    if (preg_match($pattern_windows1265, $str_windows1265, $matches) > 0) {
        echo $str, '<br />';
    }
}
```

when executing, it will output:

```
لدي أربعة أولاد
لدي خمسة أرانب
```

I removed some of the pattern to check if the plain check against Arabic works, which seems to be working.

Comment: I remember running into problems when trying with `mb_convert_encoding`, so I switched to `iconv` instead, I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: unfortunately, didn't work, it always return nothing found :( is there some php setting i have to change or so ?

Comment: thank you brother, now it works. Ramadan kareem and thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern modifier `u` to use any UTF-8 supported language.

```
if (preg_match("/\p{L}\b(?:(?:واحد|اثنان|ثلاثة|أربعة|خمسة|ستة|سبعة|ثمانية|تسعة|صفر|عشرة)\b\s*?){4}/u", $str, $matches) > 0)
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)