# regex and post variable

Tags: php, regex

when I send form and check for the arabic and english and numeric chars the code below not working :

```
<?
$username = $_POST["alalala"];
if ($username){
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9ا-ي ]+$/i", $username)){
echo "error";
}else{
echo "ok";
}  
}
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="alalala">
```

the regex can't find arabic in $_post[alalala]

**EDIT**

not working :s, the problem not in p{Arabic}

it's in finding the arabic chars only when form submit

**EDIT2** : when i change the line

```
$username = $_POST["alalala"];
```

to

```
$username = "any thing نستيتيلا";
```

the regex find the arabic chars

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add Arabic letters to url regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842378/how-to-add-arabic-letters-to-url-regex)

Comment: You need the `/u` modifier in any case. And for simplicity use the mentioned `\p{...}` thingy instead of a character range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631408/731179

```
<?php 
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\p{Arabic}0-9\s\-]+$/u", "whatever"); 
?>
```

PHP supports PCRE

http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105324
 http://fi.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`preg_match(/^(\p{Arabic}|[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/i, $username)`

Comment: not working :s, the problem not in p{Arabic}

it's in finding the arabic chars only when form submit

Comment: Use GET method and check the URL bar. There is no Arabic characters there probably.

Comment: I do that, the arabic exist in the URL bar